# StrongSwan clients fail to connect, Constraint checking failure

Tags: vpn, strongswan, ikev2

Client devices (Runs Windows 10 and Android with StrongSwan app) fail to connect. Certificates signed by one authority, CN is set as server public ip.
Here's ipsec.conf:

```
config setup
include /var/lib/strongswan/ipsec.conf.inc

config setup
    charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
    uniqueids=no

conn ikev2-vpn
    ike=aes128gcm16-sha2_256-prfsha256-ecp256!
    esp=aes128gcm16-sha2_256-ecp256!
    auto=add
    compress=no
    type=tunnel
    keyexchange=ikev2
    fragmentation=yes
    forceencaps=yes
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    rekey=no
    left=%any
    leftid=18.193.252.13
    leftcert=server-cert.pem
    leftsendcert=always
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    right=%any
    rightid=%any
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightsourceip=10.10.10.0/24
    rightdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
    rightsendcert=never
    eap_identity=%identity
```

Here's syslog:

```
Feb 19 07:03:03 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 10[NET] received packet: from 202.160.39.38[48240] to 172.26.11.47[500] (716 bytes)
Feb 19 07:03:03 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 10[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
Feb 19 07:03:03 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 10[IKE] 202.160.39.38 is initiating an IKE_SA
Feb 19 07:03:03 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 10[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
Feb 19 07:03:03 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 10[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
Feb 19 07:03:03 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 10[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(MULT_AUTH) ]
Feb 19 07:03:03 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 10[NET] sending packet: from 172.26.11.47[500] to 202.160.39.38[48240] (264 bytes)
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 11[NET] received packet: from 202.160.39.38[39128] to 172.26.11.47[4500] (421 bytes)
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 11[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) CPRQ(ADDR ADDR6 DNS DNS6) N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(NO_ADD_ADDR) N(MULT_AUTH) N(EAP_ONLY) N(MSG_ID_SYN_SUP) ]
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 11[IKE] initiating EAP_IDENTITY method (id 0x00)
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 11[IKE] received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 11[IKE] peer supports MOBIKE
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 11[IKE] authentication of 'CN=public ip' (myself) with RSA_EMSA_PKCS1_SHA2_384 successful
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 11[IKE] sending end entity cert "CN=public ip"
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 11[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr CERT AUTH EAP/REQ/ID ]
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 11[ENC] splitting IKE message (1942 bytes) into 2 fragments
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 11[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(1/2) ]
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 11[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(2/2) ]
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 11[NET] sending packet: from 172.26.11.47[4500] to 202.160.39.38[39128] (1248 bytes)
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 11[NET] sending packet: from 172.26.11.47[4500] to 202.160.39.38[39128] (759 bytes)
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 12[NET] received packet: from 202.160.39.38[39128] to 172.26.11.47[4500] (65 bytes)
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 12[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL request 2 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 12[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL response 2 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
Feb 19 07:03:04 ip-172-26-11-47 charon: 12[NET] sending packet: from 172.26.11.47[4500] to 202.160.39.38[39128] (65 bytes)
```

And log from Android device:

```
Feb 19 09:27:42 00[DMN] Starting IKE service (strongSwan 5.9.1rc1, Android 8.0.0 - OPR1.170623.026/2019-04-01, LG-H930 - lge/joan_global_com/LGE, Linux 4.4.78-perf+, aarch64)
Feb 19 09:27:42 00[LIB] loaded plugins: androidbridge charon android-log openssl fips-prf random nonce pubkey chapoly curve25519 pkcs1 pkcs8 pem xcbc hmac socket-default revocation eap-identity eap-mschapv2 eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-tls x509
Feb 19 09:27:42 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
Feb 19 09:27:42 13[IKE] initiating IKE_SA android[10] to public ip
Feb 19 09:27:42 13[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
Feb 19 09:27:42 13[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.100.27[58880] to public ip[500] (716 bytes)
Feb 19 09:27:43 08[NET] received packet: from public ip[500] to 192.168.100.27[58880] (264 bytes)
Feb 19 09:27:43 08[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(MULT_AUTH) ]
Feb 19 09:27:43 08[CFG] selected proposal: IKE:AES_GCM_16_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/ECP_256
Feb 19 09:27:43 08[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
Feb 19 09:27:43 08[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
Feb 19 09:27:43 08[IKE] establishing CHILD_SA android{10}
Feb 19 09:27:43 08[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) CPRQ(ADDR ADDR6 DNS DNS6) N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(NO_ADD_ADDR) N(MULT_AUTH) N(EAP_ONLY) N(MSG_ID_SYN_SUP) ]
Feb 19 09:27:43 08[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.100.27[55399] to public ip[4500] (421 bytes)
Feb 19 09:27:43 09[NET] received packet: from public ip[4500] to 192.168.100.27[55399] (1248 bytes)
Feb 19 09:27:43 09[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(1/2) ]
Feb 19 09:27:43 09[ENC] received fragment #1 of 2, waiting for complete IKE message
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[NET] received packet: from public ip[4500] to 192.168.100.27[55399] (759 bytes)
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(2/2) ]
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[ENC] received fragment #2 of 2, reassembled fragmented IKE message (1942 bytes)
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr CERT AUTH EAP/REQ/ID ]
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[IKE] received end entity cert "CN=public ip"
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[CFG]   using trusted certificate "CN=public ip"
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[IKE] signature validation failed, looking for another key
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[CFG]   using certificate "CN=public ip"
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[CFG]   using trusted ca certificate "CN=public ip"
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[CFG] checking certificate status of "CN=public ip"
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[CFG] certificate status is not available
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[CFG]   reached self-signed root ca with a path length of 0
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[IKE] authentication of 'CN=public ip' with RSA_EMSA_PKCS1_SHA2_384 successful
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[CFG] constraint check failed: identity 'public ip' required 
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[CFG] selected peer config 'android' unacceptable: constraint checking failed
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[CFG] no alternative config found
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL request 2 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.100.27[55399] to public ip[4500] (65 bytes)
```

Both devices used to work with StrongSwan, i configured a year ago with no problems at all. This is new VM on AWS, actually for client devices i just changed password (according to new /ipsec.secrets) and imported new CA certificate accordingly. Where can my mistake be? Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 1):

```
Feb 19 09:27:43 10[CFG] constraint check failed: identity 'public ip' required
```

Your server certificate apparently does not contain the IP address you configured on the client as *subjectAltName* (SAN) extension. You can either issue a new certificate that includes the IP or hostname you configure on the client as SAN, or you explicitly configure the identity of the server on the client (for the strongSwan Android client, you can do so in the advanced VPN profile settings).

Comment: Thanks for reply, will try to issue new certificate. Can it be reason for raising "Signature validation failure" that comes before constraint  checking failure? Never had it in logs before

Comment: No, that's because your CA and end-entity certificates apparently use the same subject DN (so both are tried when validating the end-entity certificate).

Comment: Thanks! You were absolutely correct, i issued new certificates and that solved the case.